# NST\autoneogrub0.mbr missing

Tags: grub, ubuntu

I have an HP Envy Laptop with Windows 8.1 installed. I have disabled EUFI from the boot menu so that I could boot from a flash drive in order to install LUbuntu.

I have installed LUbuntu on a 3 separate partitions (the main big one, swap-file and bios root).

I have then used EasyBSD to add LUbuntu to the boot menu.

However, when I try to boot to Lubuntu from the boot menu, I get a message saying that

```
\NS\autoneogrub0.mb
```

is missing.

What is going wrong?

Looking in more detail, my EasyBCD DisplayMode Overview shows:

There are a total of 8 entries listed in the bootloader.

```
Default: Not set
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: D:\

Entry #1
Name: Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
BCD ID: {8fc567c6-d7b0-11e4-9454-c3522382cf45}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #2
Name: USB Drive (UEFI)
BCD ID: {8fc567c2-d7b0-11e4-9454-c3522382cf45}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #3
Name: Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
BCD ID: {8fc567c3-d7b0-11e4-9454-c3522382cf45}
Device: Unknown
Bootloader Path: 

Entry #4
Name: Windows 8.1
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.efi

Entry #5
Name: Lubuntu
BCD ID: {eabbb4d1-d76f-11e4-825c-40e2303afcfa}
Drive: D:\
Bootloader Path: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
```

The setting believes that LUbuntu is on drive D. But it is not on Drive D. It is on Partitions 6 (big), 7 (swap) and 8 (bios root)

Answer (score -1):

EasyBCD is not great when it comes to UEFI Systems. Read:
https://neosmart.net/forums/threads/easybcd-is-deadly-dangerous-on-uefi-systems.9342/
Did you make a boot configuration restore point ?
If you did, refer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/230878/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-with-windows-8-boot-manager